# Not able to add float from input box in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 classes on 4 different input box they are:

`class1`
`class2`
`class3`
`class4`

My javascript code looks like:

```
$("body").on("focusout", ".class1", function () {
 var basic = parseFloat($(".class2").val());
 var hra = parseFloat($(".class3").val());
 var tot = basic + hra;
 $(".class4").val(tot);
});
```

But at the end i am getting empty stringin `tot`.
I need to calulate sum of `class2` and `class3` and assign to `class4`.

Comment: Can you provide a complete working example?

Comment: Check first if both float values aren't `NaN`. Also make sure your `.class1` and `.class2` elements are input fields. `.val()` only works on form elements.

Comment: When i remove the parseFloat() the value are being assigned to basic but after adding parseFloat() empty string is coming.

Comment: @Tyr by form elements do you mean the input box wrapped inside form tag

Comment: No, it's not necessary that input elements must be wrapped in a form element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it in this way!

> Code included inside [`$(function(){ ...  });`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute

```js
$(function(){


  $("body").on("focusout", ".class1", function () {
     var basic = parseFloat($(".class2").val());
     var hra = parseFloat($(".class3").val());
    console.log(basic, hra);
     var tot = basic + hra;
      $(".class4").val(tot);
     
  });



})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="class1" value="0"><br>
<input class="class2" value="0"><br>
<input class="class3" value="0"><br>
<input class="class4" value="0">
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @saumyarastogi for the solution.It worked..!! Can you please tell why `$(function(){` is used in beginning.

Comment: Its used for making the script loaded automatically as soon as the page fully loads! Did you get it?

Comment: Yes it is the alias, see the link in my updated answer!

Comment: Ok thnx for the help.